# nhibernate freeware disgner plugin for visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nhibernate

I'm new to and ORMs.

Does anyone know of a recommended free nhibernate designer plugin for visual studio 2010?

mainly for easy mapping.

Comment: FYI, you can take the problem the other way around and build the class model first. And therefore use the class designer of Visual Studio to build your model and use Fluent nHibernate to make the mapping seamlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [NHibernate Designer](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/nhdesigner) from mindscape, but it's only free for 10 entities or less.

It's also available for download [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1789e1f3-81a8-4667-967b-e4dc0bbbdf21).

Comment: @EladBenda It's also available on the Visual studio gallery website (I added a link to it)

Comment: Fixed the link - sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to consider something outside visual studio, you can try [Visual Nhibernate](http://www.slyce.com/)